# Can a checkbox be checked by default in the stylesheet, rather than in an HTML attribute?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, checked

Like the title says: can a checkbox be checked by default in the stylesheet, rather than in an inline HTML attribute?

Example from w3schools.com, the "car" box is checked:

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I'm making an "I agree to the Terms and Conditions" checkbox, and due to the clunky website I'm making this on, I can't create inline CSS. Instead, I can assign this field a css class, and edit the class in the larger stylesheet.

If it makes it easier, this will be the only checkbox on the page.

Comment: That is not `css`.. it is attribute of that element.. and to be more precise `css` cant do that at all. you'll need to use `js`.

Comment: I'm not sure this is legal.

Comment: Everyone had good answers for working around, but @TylerH had the most useful comment: "I'm not sure this is legal". 

I should leave the T&C box UNCHECKED by default, since the user has to actively agree to the T&C. Otherwise, there might be some sort of legal vulnerability. 

Thanks everyone for the speedy responses!! Now I get to tell my boss how I probably just avoided getting us into legal trouble!


(For posterity: another solution could have been some text above the submit button, saying "By clicking submit, you agree to T&C)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A checkbox cannot be checked in CSS, unfortunately. It relies on the `checked` attribute of the `input` element, and attributes cannot be modified via CSS.

Alternatively, you could look into a JavaScript solution, but of course the best way would be to edit the HTML directly.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this is not a css but a html element's attribute.

Another way to check it is with javascript, and with css you can only select it like this:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked  /* select checked checkbox */
input[type=checkbox]  /* select any checkbox */
```